# Jetson Orin Deepstream vs conventional python program

Tags: opencv, nvidia, nvidia-deepstream

Does anyone have a independent evaluation of using Deepstream Gstream pipline instead of a conventional python code?

Gstreamer:
USB-CAM -> Appsink -> (CPU to GPU) AI analysis (TensorRT) -> CV2.ImShow

I think I understand that deepstream uses the GPU only in the gstreamer pipeline but is it faster. Any comparison. Where/what do I gain by using the deepstreamer?

Answer (score 1):

[GStreamer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GStreamer) is a pipeline-based multimedia framework that links together a wide variety of media processing systems to complete complex workflows. For instance, GStreamer can be used to build a system that reads files in one format, processes them, and exports them in another. The formats and processes can be changed in a plug and play fashion.

Deepstream utilizes gstreamer to do some tasks in a cascade routine. As

Deepstream feed input streams to the pipeline and since gstreamer has different plugins, streams pass through this pipeline. Nvidia made some plugin in addition to gstreamer plugin.

For example *pgie, tracker , tiler, nvvidconv, nvosd, transform, sink* and ... are some of them. Deepstream runs **main loop** on **GPU**, so primary model and secondary models could do inferences. Accessing to output of each plugins- like **pgie** or **sgie**- is possible via **metadata**. These metadatas includes frame data, object location, time of occurrence and .... It is possible to access these metadata via some function in plugins like **gstdsexample**. Having these data make it easy to do process on a stream like data.

Alongside these benefit it(Deepstream) has some disadvantages: making a complex pipeline and working with it, is hard.

When you have a stream data(video, text, speech, image and ...) it's better to utilize this pipeline. Also, python and C++ implementation is possible.

Comment: Thanks for the input.

I am still puzzled. Most people still utilizes other means that using deepstream so there must be something that makes it bad. nVidia themselves seems to push for it but there is not any good examples or support by the communities so I guess its not common utility yet.

Comment: @Magnus_G Deepstream is not completely open source platform. So sometimes it is challenging work with it.

Comment: What could you do with deepstream completely depends on how nvidia brings facilities to us. Sometimes it not presents open source codes for some functionalities and it guides me to trouble.

Comment: Also don't forget the ability to use hardware encoders/decoders in an easy manner through gstreamer/deepstream which can be something not trivial to do in a standalone implementation. An example can be nvjpegenc/dec that uses Nvidia's hardware jpeg encoder which is way faster than any software implementation.

Comment: I have had some discussions with Ultralytics working on yolo and deepstream and my it verify my understanding that using python code and not deepstream affects performance heavily.

To use nVidia framwork provides the oportunity to maximize the utilization of hradware accelerated processing. So GPU is obvious but also memory buffers etc speeds up the process.

So using deepstream is a better option if you can get the pipeline to work, which is a tremendous hazzle. OpenCV on the other hand is easy and you can get started but put alot of overhead into copying and CPU processing.